# Why my code can't pass the leetcode submission while the same test case in "Run code" pass it

Tags: go, testcase

Link to the problem: [653. Two Sum IV - Input is a BST](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum-iv-input-is-a-bst/)
My code can't pass same test case for submission:

```golang
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * type TreeNode struct {
 *     Val int
 *     Left *TreeNode
 *     Right *TreeNode
 * }
 */

var Begin *TreeNode=nil

func findTarget(root *TreeNode, k int) bool {
    if(Begin==nil){
        Begin=root
    }
    if(root==nil){
        return false
    }
    if(search(root,k-root.Val)==true){
        return true
    }
    return findTarget(root.Left,k) || findTarget(root.Right,k)
}

func search(node *TreeNode,complement int) bool{
    var curr *TreeNode=Begin
    for curr!=nil{
        if(complement>curr.Val){
            curr=curr.Right
        }else if(complement<curr.Val){
            curr=curr.Left
        }else{
            if(curr==node){
                return false
            }else{
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I have written it in c++、java、python with the same logic ,all pass the submission , the strange thing is that I use this test case(I copy the test case from the submission wrong alerting)
" [0,-1,2,-3,null,null,4],-4 " the "Run Code" process accept the result,but the submission with the same test case,it still alerts wrong submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `Begin` is declared before everything and it doesn't always initialize as `nil`. Try something like:

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * type TreeNode struct {
 *     Val int
 *     Left *TreeNode
 *     Right *TreeNode
 * }
 */
func foo(root * TreeNode, k int, Begin * TreeNode) bool {
    if (Begin == nil) {
        Begin = root
    }
    if (root == nil) {
        return false
    }
    if search(root, k - root.Val, Begin) {
        return true
    }
    return foo(root.Left, k, Begin) || foo(root.Right, k, Begin)
}


func findTarget(root * TreeNode, k int) bool {
    var Begin * TreeNode = nil
    return foo(root, k, Begin)
}

func search(node * TreeNode, complement int, Begin * TreeNode) bool {
    var curr * TreeNode = Begin
    for curr != nil {
        if (complement > curr.Val) {
            curr = curr.Right
        } else if (complement < curr.Val) {
            curr = curr.Left
        } else {
            if (curr == node) {
                return false
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: thanks,in my mind,I find it strange in "Begin" declaration,but I don't know how to adjust it, in c++ java,they have "this" ,python has "self"  also,   Thanks a lot , the key point is that "Begin" doesn't always initialize as nil.  Though the "Run code" process may pass,the submission is strict a lot to pass it

Comment: Well, one way is to initialize default value in one function and then pass it as parameter to another function. That way, for each test, `Begin` will have `nil` at first.

Comment: got it ,I appreciate it